# In unity how can i do additional stuff after creating an asset in the editor?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, automation, editor

I want to extend the functionality creating a scene. Right now I just right click in the project view in the folder where I want the asset to be created, choose "Create", and pick "Scene" and then I make this scene addressable, put it into a scriptable object and so on. I'd like to make this process automatic. Is there a way to extend Unity create asset menu options? Mainly I'd love if after pressing create scene a dialogue box would pop up which would handle the rest of the process.

I tried looking for options online but I couldn't find examples of this anywhere. Is this possible to do in Unity?

Comment: How about the [CreateAssetMenuAttribute](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CreateAssetMenuAttribute.html) attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m sure you will not find any related example because your use case is unique.

Try to find an example for every step you are described above.

I will try to explain process step by step, but you will have to do the coding part by yourself.

- use [CreateAssetMenuAttribute](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CreateAssetMenuAttribute.html) as [Juris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14780897/juris) mentioned
- use [NewScene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.html) method from [EditorSceneManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.html) object which is responsible for managing of scenes in the editor
- use [DisplayDialog](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.DisplayDialog.html) method from [EditorUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.DisplayDialog.html) object for dialog
- use this [thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/creating-addressable-asset-from-editor-script.987717/) to create addressable from your scene
- use [CreateInstance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.html) method from [ScriptableObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.html) object to create scriptable object
- use i.e [LoadAssetAtPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneAsset.html) from [AssetDatabase](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneAsset.html) object to load created scene into ScriptableObject

This is very general answer but I hope it will give some clue how to solve your problem.